# Aurora - MySQL 5.7 - Adaptive_hash_index Config - Read Vs Write Replicas

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I am running an Aurora MySQL 5.7. I have set up adaptive hash index to true at the db level for each instance. The Write instance is set to true but the read replica is still set to false. Not sure why. Is this not possible to change?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known and verified (undocumented) limitation of Aurora. According to the Percona blog post "[Adaptive Hash Index on AWS Aurora](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/06/25/adaptive-hash-index-on-aws-aurora/)", AWS engineers have confirmed that Adaptive Hash Index cannot be enabled on the Reader nodes. If you have workloads that require AHI, you need to run them on the Writer node or on a separate MySQL replica.

The fact that you can still modify this Parameter Group parameter on a Reader instance (where the parameter has no effect) appears to be a bug they are looking into.

See also [this Aug 2015 AWS forum post by Stefano@AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=672155#672155) which confirms this limitation:

> Question on performance of queries with joins across large datasets. As some have pointed out, enabling innodb_adaptive_hash_index can improve this class of query. The parameter is disabled by default in Aurora as it can be detrimental on performance intensive mixed read/write workloads, but can be re-enabled at any time via parameter group. I can confirm that at the moment the parameter is only honored on the master instance of the cluster and not by read replicas. It is possible to workaround the limitation by creating a separate Aurora instance and enabling binlog replication, which is something we support. This is an area where we have improvements planned and are currently working on.